# [symfony 1.4][sfForm] hide | un-hide row

Tags: ajax, symfony1, symfony-forms

How to hide row and un-hide it with Ajax ( how to put whole row in div with id ) ?

Comment: Please explain your question better

Comment: You can control how you echo your form. How are you doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in javascript you can reference to any object in your html code with a defined 'id' My suggestion is to use a css class for rour row and use an script like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $(".your_hide_button").click(function(e){  
      $(".your_row").css("display", "none");    
  });  
});  
</script>
```

Hope this helped you, good luck